# Joomla system messages not showing in custom template - Contact Form validation

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am using joomla's contact us form with a custom template I built.
When I submit the form, I am not getting any form validation error messages.
When I change the template to Beez3, the validation messages are showing.

Please help me from this issue.

Comment: which kind of errors do you mean? Can you attach a screenshot with the errors that appear with Beez3?

Comment: Error message showing is => Invalid field:  Name

Comment: my question is more about where your form displays this error, rather than the error itself. So please can you attach a screenshot with the error?

Comment: error messages shows just above the form

Comment: in your custom template, have you included the <jdoc:include type="message" /> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out through the comments conversation, it proved that you haven't included in your template, the `<jdoc:include type="message" />`, which is carrying and return any system messages.

So, on top of the `<jdoc:include type="component" />`, add the `<jdoc:include type="message" />`, in order to have Joomla outputting the system messages.

This refers to all kind of messages and is not specific to your form.

Comment: how is it possible to place the validation error messages corresponding to the text fields? All the messages are showing together on top of the form. Is it possible to place the error below the corresponding textfields.

Comment: Not sure how easy would be to do this with the server side validation, but you could add client side validation to a template override of the form with some javascript. Have a look here. [Client Side Validation](https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation)

Comment: Alternatively you can use a 3rd party form extension - there are plenty of them and many free as well.